# How to get back my Teams meeting link?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams

A while ago, I have set up a meeting in Outlook's calendar and invited some colleagues.

Now, we have come to the decision to use MS Teams for this meeting, so I clicked the "Teams Meeting" button in the toolbar for the event. This caused Outlook to

- put "Microsoft Teams" into the location field and
- write a link to the Teams meeting into the body of the event and
- replace the "Teams Meeting" toolbar button with a "Join Teams Meeting" button that will directly open MS Teams.

As the list of external participants that would be invited was not quite finalized yet and I did not want to send all those that had signed up already too many event updates, I chose not to save the event and send updates for now, intending to come back later.

Now, an hour later, I received the full list of external participants. Ready to edit my event, I see that the auto-generated location and the body are both gone (as expected, because I did not save my changes before).

**However, the toolbar button "Teams Meeting" is *still* gone, I just have the "Join Teams Meeting" button!**

That's great, now I can join the meeting, but no-one else can, because I do not have the link anymore.

I can live with the location not being set to "Microsoft Teams" (I can obviously type that text myself, though I seem to remember there was some special formatting to it), but **how do I get back my meeting link that I can put into the event body?**

Comment: Best bet is probably to delete the meeting and start again, as you haven't sent it yet.

Comment: @theBenB: Oh, I had sent the meeting already to the initial set of (internal) contacts. What I hadn't sent was the update about the meeting taking place on Teams. But I think I have found a solution in the meantime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally found a solution:

Once I have joined the meeting on MS Teams, I can open the list of participants.

In there, I have the option of inviting additional participants, and next to the respective input box, there is a tiny button with a chain/link icon. Clicking it will copy just the "Join Teams Meeting" text with the appropriate link to the clipboard that I can then paste into the event body again.

So, there's no direct way from within Outlook (and I do have to consider the fact that the "Teams Meeting" button won't come back a bug), but at least there is *some* way to restore the Teams meeting invite.

Comment: Make sure the format of your invitation is set to HTML or Rich Text (Ribbon->Format Text->Format). In case of Plain Text, only the text "Join Microsoft Teams Meeting" is pasted, without a link.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I got distracted for 15 minutes or so and when I came back, the "Teams Meeting" button was back! Try holding out for a bit and see if it comes back on its own.